# Intel XDK AdMob property cannot read property 'AdMob' of undefined

Tags: admob, undefined, cordova-plugins, intel-xdk

I am very desperate because i simply can´t figure out what I do wrong. I have troubles using AdMob with Intel XDK. I get always an error while debugging:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'AdMob' of undefined

All plugins are activated and i have no clue why this error occurs.
For example I can even use easy Templates for Trying to use AdMob like this one:

https://github.com/floatinghotpot/testadmob4xdk
normally imported with Third Party Plugin : Admob, but i still get this errors.

Or copy and pasted this one:
https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro/wiki/02.-How-to-Use-with-Intel-XDK and done the steps but still this error.

Even on the devices i get this error, not the debugger where 3rd party plugins aren´t supported.

I would really appreciate help because it is driving me crazy.
(I have the same problem with just using Cordova, without Intel XDK)

Thank you very much,
SirSandmann

Comment: You can try with [this admob-google-xdk](https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-xdk) step-by-step tutorial. And the plugin source: https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova. One question: are you testing in a browser or in a device? If it is a browser or intel emulator, it won't work, it must be a device or native emulator

Comment: Thank for your help, I figured out you actually have to build it. Debugging on device isn´t woking too. So building your App and then transfer it to your device is the only possibility to test it with Intel XDK.

Comment: @SirSandmann for custom plugins, you must do builds to get the native code to work...it does not exist in App Preview